# Creating an Array of all patient's weight measures in different appointments

Tags: google-app-maker

### Scenario

Patients schedules 'appointments' and come to the clinic. Before they get examined by the doctor, their 'measures' are taken.
These measures are 'Weight', 'Height' and 'Head' size. To complete the data needed, their 'age' comes to the record too.

---

### What I am trying to do:

I want to create a chart that shows if the Weight of a patient (for example) is over/under the limits, and to accomplish that **I need to create an array with all the previous measures of the patient**.

---

### Example:

```
- John (id:12) comes to appointment#1 (id:55) on jan,1 2019; he have 1 month age; his Measures (id:47): Weight=30kg, Height=120cm, Head=[not taken];
- John (id:12) comes to appointment#2 (id:67) on feb,3 2019; he have 2 month age; his Measures (id:72): Weight=35kg, Height=127cm, Head=[not taken];
- John (id:12) comes to appointment#3 (id:89) on mar,9 2019; he have 3 month age; and none of his Measures are taken;
- John (id:12) comes to appointment#4 (id:99) on apr,5 2019; he have 4 month age; his Measures (id:93): Weight=42kg, Height=135cm, Head=[not taken];
```

### Result Needed:

```
    weightArray = {"30","35",,"42"}
    heightArray = {"120","127",,"135"}
    headArray = {,,,}
```

**Legend:**

***array-Name*** = {**measure-With-One-Month-Age**, **measure-With-Two-Months-Age**, **measure-With-Three-Months-Age**, **etc**... }

---

### Datasources Structure:

```
app.datasources.Patients.item.idPatient
                             .Name

app.datasources.Appointments.item.idAppointment
                                 .Date
                                 .Time
                            .relations.Measures.item.idMeasure  (one to one)
                                                    .Weight
                                                    .Height
                                                    .Head
                                                    .Age
                            .relations.Patients (many to one)
```

---

### Workflow:

- We create new patients directly into the "**Patients**" datasource ;
- When an **Appointment** is created, we select a "**Patients**" record for the "**Appointments > Patients**" relation ;
- When the patient arrives in the clinic, we create a "**Measures**" record inside the "**Appointments > Measures**" relation.

---

### Client-side Code

### (I have tried a lot of different codes with no success, this was just my last unsuccessful try):

```
function getHistoryPatient (patientId){
  var weightArr = [], heightArr = [], headArr = [], ageArr = [];
  var dataSource = app.datasources.Appointments;
    dataSource.query.filters.Patients.idPatient._equals = patientId;
    dataSource.load(function (){
      var appointmentItems = dataSource.items.forEach(function (appointment){
        var data = appointment.Measures;
        weightArr.push(data.Weight);    
        heightArr.push(data.Height);
        headArr.push(data.Head);
        ageArr.push(data.Age);
      });
    });
  return {Age: ageArr, Weight: weightArr, Height: heightArr, Head: headArr};
}
```

Actually, calling: **getHistoryPatient(patientId).Weight**, for example, returns nothing, including no errors.

So, how could I return these arrays?

Comment: Does it matter if your measurements are into separate arrays for weight, height, and head measurement? I mean why don’t you just have appointment, when selecting the appointment you go to appointment detail which list the patient relation and then lists a table with the measurements relation sorted by either appointment date or age. I don’t think there’s a need to make separate arrays, I would just work off filtering the patient and then displaying the measurements relation of the patient.

Comment: To create the Growth Charts the data needs to be separated in different arrays required by the Chart.js library. But reading your answer I thought about pushing each measurement value to a record on patients datasource itself. Besides the need to change the datasource model, making this way the array might be "automatically" created on every appointment. I'll try that.

Comment: If you’re doing a chart why not leave them all in the same datasource and then I believe the built in charts widgets should be able to graph individual items out of the datasource. I would try that before separating everything out into separate datasources.

Comment: I've make it work by doing exactly what you said: Every time a new measure is taken, it's saved into a record on the same ("Patients") datasource. The charts are working now! Thank you for your help.